# Tooltip is getting cut off from the top inside table with vertical scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one table and for each table cell I am showing one tool-tip on hovering of table-cell. Problem with this is when table is having scroll  and the tool tip content is very large then it is getting cut off from the top.

I am using below css styling for showing tool-tip.

```
.CellWithComment{
  position:relative;
}

.CellComment{
  display:none;
  position:absolute; 
  z-index:100;
  border:1px;
  background-color:white;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;
  border-color:red;
  padding:3px;
  color:red; 
  bottom:20px; 
  left:20px;
}
```

I made a fiddle 
[table with tooltip](https://jsfiddle.net/qcnu0081/1/). 
you can hover the first column of first row to see the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right path. Instead of positioning the comment from the bottom you can position from top. Also i added some comment to the code see below.

```css
#MyTable{
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:black;
  border-width:2px
}

#MyTable td{
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:black;
  border-width:1px;
  padding:3px;
}

.CellWithComment{
  position:relative;
}

.CellComment{
  display:none;
  position:absolute; 
  z-index:100;
  border:1px;
  background-color:white;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;
  border-color:red;
  padding:3px;
  color:red; 
  bottom:20px; 
  left:20px;
  width: 130px; 
  max-height: 37px; 
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.CellWithComment:hover span.CellComment{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:200px;overflow:auto;margin-top:40px">
<table id="MyTable">
  <caption>Cell 1,2 Has a Comment</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Heading 1</td>
      <td>Heading 2</td>
      <td>Heading 3</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td class="CellWithComment">Cell 1,2
        <span class="CellComment">That is going to be a really big tool-tip text. </span>
      </td>
      <td>Cell 1,1</td>
     
      <td>Cell 1,3</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
     <td class="CellWithComment">Cell 1,2
        <span class="CellComment">Here is a comment</span>
      </td>
      <td>Cell 1,1</td>
     
      <td>Cell 1,3</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
     <td class="CellWithComment">Cell 1,2
        <span class="CellComment">Here is a comment</span>
      </td>
      <td>Cell 1,1</td>
     
      <td>Cell 1,3</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
     <td class="CellWithComment">Cell 1,2
        <span class="CellComment">Here is a comment</span>
      </td>
      <td>Cell 1,1</td>
     
      <td>Cell 1,3</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
     <td class="CellWithComment">Cell 1,2
        <span class="CellComment">Here is a comment</span>
      </td>
      <td>Cell 1,1</td>
     
      <td>Cell 1,3</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
     <td class="CellWithComment">Cell 1,2
        <span class="CellComment">Here is a comment</span>
      </td>
      <td>Cell 1,1</td>
     
      <td>Cell 1,3</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
     <td class="CellWithComment">Cell 1,2
        <span class="CellComment">Here is a comment</span>
      </td>
      <td>Cell 1,1</td>
     
      <td>Cell 1,3</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
     <td class="CellWithComment">Cell 1,2
        <span class="CellComment">Here is a comment</span>
      </td>
      <td>Cell 1,1</td>
     
      <td>Cell 1,3</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
     <td class="CellWithComment">Cell 1,2
        <span class="CellComment">Here is a comment</span>
      </td>
      <td>Cell 1,1</td>
     
      <td>Cell 1,3</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
     <td class="CellWithComment">Cell 1,2
        <span class="CellComment">Here is a comment</span>
      </td>
      <td>Cell 1,1</td>
     
      <td>Cell 1,3</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
     <td class="CellWithComment">Cell 1,2
        <span class="CellComment">Here is a comment</span>
      </td>
      <td>Cell 1,1</td>
     
      <td>Cell 1,3</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
     <td class="CellWithComment">Cell 1,2
        <span class="CellComment">Here is a comment</span>
      </td>
      <td>Cell 1,1</td>
     
      <td>Cell 1,3</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
     <td class="CellWithComment">Cell 1,2
        <span class="CellComment">Here is a comment</span>
      </td>
      <td>Cell 1,1</td>
     
      <td>Cell 1,3</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
     <td class="CellWithComment">Cell 1,2
        <span class="CellComment">Here is a comment</span>
      </td>
      <td>Cell 1,1</td>
     
      <td>Cell 1,3</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
     <td class="CellWithComment">Cell 1,2
        <span class="CellComment">Here is a comment</span>
      </td>
      <td>Cell 1,1</td>
     
      <td>Cell 1,3</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
     <td class="CellWithComment">Cell 1,2
        <span class="CellComment">Here is a comment</span>
      </td>
      <td>Cell 1,1</td>
     
      <td>Cell 1,3</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
     <td class="CellWithComment">Cell 1,2
        <span class="CellComment">Here is a comment</span>
      </td>
      <td>Cell 1,1</td>
     
      <td>Cell 1,3</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 2,1</td>
      <td>Cell 2,2</td>
      <td>Cell 2,3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi blecaf. Actually that is not my requirement. I want to show the tooltip just above the table cell content. that is why I used bottom.  and it should be always visible irrespective of the tooltip content length.

Comment: Will advise to put an overflow on the comment and max-height. Updated my code. I don't think i know any other way for that to be possible without looking weird maybe js